# how to count in mysql records of joined tables with records limit?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have 2 tables, which i want to count the joined records between them:

suppliers and supplier_addresses

each supplier can have non or many addresses, so I want to count for the first 5 suppliers how many addresses they have.

tried something like:

```
select count(*) from suppliers inner join supplier_addresses limit 5;
```

but its not working, what should I do here?

Comment: Please avoid `count(*)` instead `count(id)` or some specific field, its more efficient

Comment: "not working" means what? An error? Unexpected results? I can guess, but try to be specific about what your issue is, it helps. By the way, why the "first 5" only? And first by what? ID? Name? (Remember that being first in the table is meaningless - SQL tables don't inherently have an order. in theory if you select without specifying an order, the DB is allowed to give you the results in any order it likes)

Comment: 'first 5 suppliers' - alphabetically, by sales??

Comment: @ADyson sorry. i get the results off all the join, not only 5 records.

Comment: Ok well to help you more you need to answer the question about how you determine the "first 5". Actually, showing us some sample data and then your expected query result would make it 100% clearer.

Comment: @ADyson just the first 5 records in supplier...suppliers id 1-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must group addresses by suppliers with help GROUP BY statement for correct calculating by each supplier. For example:

```
SELECT 
   suppliers.id,
   count(*) 
FROM suppliers 
INNER JOIN supplier_addresses ON suppliers.id = supplier_addresses.supplier_id
GROUP BY suppliers.id
LIMIT 5;
```

If you want to get amount of addresses by 5 suppliers you could use subquery. For example:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM supplier_addresses 
WHERE supplier_id IN (
   SELECT id
   FROM suppliers
   LIMIT 5)
```

Of course, you can use defined identifiers of suppliers^

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM supplier_addresses 
WHERE supplier_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: how can i sum the count? instead of getting a table of id and number of records?

Comment: what i really needed is the sum and not a table of id and its sum...@Maxim Fedorov

Comment: when running the middle command i get ```RROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'``` :\ i use one of the newest mysql version